# Inserting breaks in variables over a certain length

Tags: python

So basically what I want to do is if the random string of characters generated is over 6 chars long it adds a space in a random place in that string and then the remaining ones are added on after the space so for example: raw output: "aoneicse", what I want : "aoneic se" or "aone icse".
Here is my code:

```
import random
alist = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
blist = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
clist = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
# define the 3 words
a = ''.join(random.choices(alist, k = random.randint(2,8)))
b = ''.join(random.choices(blist, k = random.randint(2,8)))
c = ''.join(random.choices(clist, k = random.randint(2,8)))
# each letter is a certain word, if this word exceeds 6 characters add a space in a random place
if a length = > 6:
    asp = [a + " "]
if b length = > 6:
    bsp = [b + " "]
if c length = > 6:
    csp = [c + " "]
# or something along the lines of this i guess
```

This code does not currently work, BTW.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a list of strings with every letter of the alphabet, there's already a `string` module that does that for you:

```py
import string

print(' ' + string.ascii_lowercase)
# Outputs  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

You also don't need to create three different variables, you can just use a single one and use that:

```py
import string

base_str = ' ' + string.ascii_lowercase
```

Then, you can use a list to generate your words based on this string:

```
import random
import string

base_str = ' ' + string.ascii_lowercase
words = [''.join(random.choices(base_str, k=random.randint(2,8))) for _ in range(3)]
```

Now, just apply your space requirement to each word:

```py
import random
import string

base_str = ' ' + string.ascii_lowercase
words = [''.join(random.choices(base_str, k=random.randint(2,8))) for _ in range(3)]

new_words = []
for word in words:
    if len(word) < 6:
        new_word = word
    else:
        pos = random.randrange(len(word))
        new_word = word[:pos] + ' ' + word[pos:]

    new_words.append(new_word)
```

Using `random.seed(0)`, `new_words` is equal to `['j xazmxvz', 'oxmg', 'buzns pcb']`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't join the choices immediately. Generate the list, and if it is long enough, pick an index in the middle (sufficiently far from either end, depending on your needs), and perform a slice assignment to the empty list at that position. Then join the list into a single string.

```
import string


a = random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=random.randint(2,8))
if len(a) > 6:
    # Adjust the arguments to randint as desired
    x = random.randint(2, len(a) - 2)
    a[x:x] = ' '
a = ''.join(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

character = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)))

def get_char():
    return character[random.randint(0, len(character) - 1)]

def gen_word(min_len, max_len):
    word = [get_char() for _ in range(random.randint(min_len, max_len))]       
    if len(word) > 6:
        word[random.randint(1, len(word) - 2)] = ' '
    return ''.join(word)

for i in range(10):
    print(gen_word(4, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d use slices to return a space, sliced-in at the right spot; Something along the lines of:

```
def split(input_str):
  if len(input_str) > 6:
    space_at = rand(0,len(input_str))
    return input_str[:space_at] + ‘ ‘ + input_str[space_at:]
  else:
    return input_str
```